# Performance of a procedure with different approach

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We created a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio and it's fire into 10 different windows.

At the same time and after that also created same stored procedure with 10 different name and these stored procedures fire into 10 different windows. Both processes take time may approx same. Please let me know which process is better for performance.

Comment: use the same name of store procedure you may called it again and again on many windows.

Comment: Store procedure name with not have any performance impact. Use one procedure and call it in multiple instances, this avoids maintaining more objects.

Comment: The process that you are following is not the right approach for measuring performance.